# I want to show usb flashdrive contents on my website

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a printing kiosk website. One of the functions is that when a user inserts their USB flash drive into the computer's USB ports, the website reads the data in that flash drive, and all the folders and contents in that flash drive show as a list on the website. Which technology can I use for that?

Currently, I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skSX6.jpg) can only access files in a specific directory on my pc using htaccess.

Comment: PHP has a variety of filesystem functions like `scandir` you could use here.

Comment: Your website can't read data from the computer where the site is being accessed (unless it so happens that the browser and the webserver are on the same device). This is for security reasons. The user would have to actively upload the files onto the site by choice.

Comment: If the usb is inserted into the webserver though then php should be able to read it just like any other filesystem

Answer (score 2):

You can't really create this kind of thing. Browser can't access users files directly. Browsers can't access filesystem for safety reasons. Think what would happend if browsers gave direct access to filesystem. Internet would not be safe place to be at as anyone would have access to your files.

Comment: OP's intention seems to be to run a webserver on the kiosk, which would have access to the USB drive. The browser would just be accessing the PHP website, which would be doing the accessing of the USB volume.